# Enable debug terminal in android x86

Tags: root-access, 4.2-jelly-bean, terminal, android-x86

I download **android-x86-4.2-20130228**

from https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-x86/downloads 
and run it as live daul boot with windows

i try to root it with **Android-x86-RootScript** but the debug terminal is disabled 
cant get console with **alt+f1**

how can i get the console ?
Or any way to root it Permanently ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you used Android-x86 from that source? The ones from official source [here](http://www.android-x86.org/download), at least the latest ones, already come pre-rooted.

Comment: I need android x86 4.2 and in this source its not found
it show 404. That’s an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried exactly the same ISO version (through VirtualBox) you mentioned and I can assure you that the Android there is pre-rooted. There is also a [SU Security app](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/com.noshufou.android.su) that manages the calls to *su*. The console shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> also works. Things are perfectly fine with that ISO.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you helped me
i have a last question 

is How can i mount all partitions i have to read it in the system

Comment: That is a different question altogether. Please ask it as a new question. Thanks. :-)